To what extent is it useful to ask a very basic question about a legacy language if it hasn't been asked before?
At my job we work with a legacy language called Magik.
At this point there is one question regarding this language on Stack Overflow.
Would it be desired to ask basic questions on how this language works to build up a useful repository of questions on Magik on Stack Overflow?
I am thinking of very basic stuff, e.g., on how to do a Hello, World! in Magik, what loops exist in Magik, etc.
I am afraid it will hurt my question résumé since it is a very niche language. I think also that some questions will be self answered by me since not a lot of people work with this.

Somewhat related: Posting questions about obscure tech if they may not get answers except from official reps

@GinoMempin this sounds like an encouragement right?

Does this answer your question? Is it OK to ask simple questions without showing your work?

@AbdulAzizBarkat no, since my question is not about simple questions in general but simple questions to build repository of knowledge about some legacy language.

@Mr.Irrelevant the same answers apply. In general, yes you can ask such questions.

Just to note, "How to do hello world" is not a Stack Overflow question. You are never going to be faced with the need to print hello world in a real application, that is the first thing you do when you start learning a new project and you want to test your development environment is setup correctly. Beyond that it is utterly pointless. Stack Overflow is for useful questions - whether they are basic or not should not have any bearing on it. Besides the fact that the more basic a question is, the more you should assume that the answer already exists.

@Gimby "How to do Hello World" could be edited / turned into "How to output something to the standard output / command line" which is a Stack Overflow question. Although some people might decide to downvote such questions its on-topic and allowed to be asked.

As you found out yourself, there might be slightly more help on gis.stackexchange.com

What do you mean by "I am afraid it will hurt my question resume"?

@Bergi Im afraid the questions won't be received well and I might lose my question privilege. That's the reason why I'm asking here before posting questions about magik.

@Mr.Irrelevant Self-answered (basic) questions are received much better than no-effort basic questions. Also niche questions will mostly be ignored altogether in my experience. I wouldn't worry about this.

@Mr.Irrelevant - If you asked clear, concise, and well researched questions then your questions should be well received.  If you asked, specifically, how to write a "hello world" question.  That would require a MRE of what you attempted and a clear concise explanation on what exactly you are having problems with. Stack Overflow is NOT a help desk, we are not here to answer questions, that you should be able to answer yourself.  Simple questions can be helpful to the community, it unfortunate, that your example of a simple question is "hello world".

If it's a question that should be covered by the most basic introduction/language description, then probably not. While there are many meta Q&A indicating basic questions are fine, they are referring to questions that aren't this  basic.
How to do a hello world/how to write a loop/etc. appear to be such questions.
Here you should really consult the language documentation, and it's not useful to try to cover this basic documentation in a ton of Q&A pairs.
Slightly less basic questions, pretty much anything that isn't covered by "language X 101" would probably be fine.
If it's as basic as a "hello world" you can consider adding this to the tag wiki of the respective language, though.

but is a question that is not a duplicate technically bad, if it can be covered by language description found online? You could say yes, because it could appear lazy, but you could also argue no, since it leads to more knowledge concentrated on SO.

To add a bit to this answer, such questions might get downvoted for lack of research but are still on-topic and shouldn't be closed.

@Mr.Irrelevant It isn't concentrated though, it's spread over many separate questions. If you want it concentrated, put it in the tag wiki of the language tag

@ErikA is the tag really the right place for such basic info, e.g. what loop types magik supports and so on?

No. I'd argue it's not. The tag wiki can link to the language's documentation, though.

Honestly, for "which loops are supported", I'd argue that's not useful at all unless there's something specific about this language (e.g. not supporting loops at all and requiring GOTOs to loop). I don't see anyone thinking "I want the exact list of loops supported in Python" or something. For the hello world, it certainly belongs in the tag wiki.

@Mr.Irrelevant - Stop worrying about seen as "lazy" and just focus on asking "clear, concise, well researched" questions.  Just remember we are not a help desk.  You are expected to bring some level of knowledge, you are suppose to know the concepts of what "hello world" consists of, at the very least.

@ErikA "I don't see anyone thinking "I want the exact list of loops supported in Python"" - on the contrary, this is a very normal thing to think! If I start writing in a new language, one of the first things I want is an overview of its control flow syntax. It'd be a bad question to ask about Python, but only because a glance at the tutorial will answer it. But there might be languages - I'm thinking about the ugly field of borderline-undocumented scripting languages built into applications - for which just "how do I write a loop" would truly be a good question of great value to others.

It seems to me though that these sort of questions that would normally be answered in your first half hour of skimming a language's tutorial or other introductory docs are probably only something we should welcome for languages where docs don't exist. What's a little frustrating to me is that it's unclear to me from the original question here to what extent Magik is in that state. From googling, I think maybe the only documentation the language has online is on the Wiki for some GIS that happens to use Magik, and there's simply no official Magik documentation to speak of at all? Not sure!

@Mark But "How do I write a for loop" is an entirely different question from "which loops are supported", and in fact one I use as an example. Similarly, questions about while loops and loops iterating over objects might be sensible. With 5 years of R experience, I can list at least 10 looping constructs, but I'm entirely sure I don't know all kinds of loops that are supported when including packages, so I would consider "which loops are supported" a strange question, and very different from "how do I loop X times/over X/recursively/parallelly/etc"

I think it's fine. There's nothing inherently wrong with a question covering beginner concepts or questions. In fact, those tend to be the most useful questions in terms of number of users who find them useful.
I'm well aware that some technologies are more popular than others. It could be that the questions you post end up not getting viewed very much. But if they're on-topic, and especially if they are questions you've genuinely had yourself, it should be fine to post these, and even encouraged to self-answer them.

I would advise you to look at the most popular (by votes, view counts, "frequency" i.e. how many times it's used as a duplicate target, etc.) questions in the tags for better-known languages and take a quick survey of what they're like. They often cover surprisingly basic material, including things that are described in the documentation (perhaps in places that aren't so easy to find). Notably, Python's documentation has a "programming FAQ" that would obviate several very popular Python questions (although they don't map one-to-one). In many of those cases, the Stack Overflow answers cite that FAQ. And these Q&As have been judged immensely useful over the years.
Please try to focus on things that are not obvious and/or could work differently, regardless of how simple they are. For example, "how do I add two numbers?" is not worth a question in a language where the answer is "use the + operator like almost every other language does"; but it is worth a question if you have to do something else. "How do I add a sequence of numbers?" is worth a question when you don't have to do it manually by writing a loop and using + - for example, using the built-in sum in Python. (There's a much more popular version of this question, but it's also terribly asked even after considerable editing.)

Thinking through the other answers on this, I think I'd say avoid the truly basic things, unless there is a specific reason to have them.  For instance, if it's something specific to the language that tripped you up around it, or it requires a nonobvious solution, or if there's some particular gotcha that needs calling out.
Simple self-answered basic things are fine, in general, but I don't think it's valuable to this community to have something utterly straightforward be documented here, especially in such a niche language.
